# how to return same letters elements with O(n) time complexity in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to solve a problem with lower time complexity which in this case `O(n)`.

Here is the problem:

```
let arr = ['dog', 'come', 'ogd', 'something', 'emoc'];
```

It should return

```
[['dog', 'ogd], ['come', 'emoc']]; // which same using letters
```

So far I solved this problem using two functions it is working great but mine is nested loop will give me `O(n2)`

Here is my code

```
const isSameChars = (str1, str2) => {
  let str1sorted = str1.split("").sort().join("");
  let str2sorted = str2.split("").sort().join("");
  if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < str1sorted.length; i++) {
    let char1 = str1sorted[i];
    let char2 = str2sorted[i];
    if (char1 !== char2) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const isSameCharElements = (arr) => {
  let result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      if (isSameChars(arr[i], arr[j]) === true) {
        result.push(arr[j])
      }
    }
  }
  return result; 
}

console.log(isSameCharElements(['dog', 'come', 'ogd', 'something', 
'emoc'])) //  [['dog', 'ogd], ['come', 'emoc']]
```

Is there any way to solve this with `O(n)` time complexity?

Thank you an advance!

Comment: So define you problem a little more. The idea is to take an array, an for each item search the rest of the array for a word that has all the same letters. Then remove both and add the pair to the result? I don't think you'll ever make that `o(n)`

Comment: Does the words always have  the first and last letter match ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a 'bag of letters' representation of any String by sorting the letters:

```
function sortLetters(word){
  return word.split('').sort().join('');
}
```

You can then iterate over your input, grouping words that have the same bag of letters representation into an object:

```
const grouped = arr.reduce(function (m, word) {
  var bagRepr = sortLetters(word);
  var withSameLetters =  m[bagRepr] || [];
  withSameLetters.push(word);
  m[bagRepr] = withSameLetters;
  return m;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(grouped)
  .filter(function (arr) {
    return arr.length > 1;  
  });
```

This is O(n), provided that `sortLetters()` is O(1), which is the case if the words lengths are bounded by a constant.

**Disclaimer:** note that we're only talking about asymptotic complexity here - this does not mean at all that this approach is the most efficient from a practical standpoint!

Comment: Technically, you'd need to then remove items that aren't part of a pair to get the output that the OP wanted. Your output would still have `something` in it. And iterating through to remove those items would be `O(n)`.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what the OP expects to happen if the input included, for example, `come`, `emoc` and `moce`. Is that supposed to be just one pair? Or all three? Or something else?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa: It is certainly true that `sortLetters` absolutely isn't `O(1)` by itself. But if `n` is the size of `arr` then it is. Because we are looking at time complexity as a function of the size of `arr` and not as a function of the length of the strings themselves.

Comment: @MattBurland oh right, I added a filter phase. Still O(n).

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa if the length of the words is bounded by a constant, then sortLetters() is O(1). More generally, sorting bounded arrays is O(1).

Comment: @MattBurland no, O(n) + O(n) is still O(n) :)

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck: D'oh. It's 2n, you're right. Still `O(n)`

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa we're not sorting the words, we're sorting the letters in each word. And reduce *is* O(n). O(n) means 'cost proportional to input size', not 'iterate fast'.

Comment: somehow it is giving me error saying that:  return word.split('').sort().join('');
              ^

TypeError: word.split is not a function

Comment: this probably means that there's some element in your input array that's not a String

Comment: can you show in fiddle please, I just checked they all string

Comment: @hackrack I'd need your input array to be able to reproduce

Comment: ['dog', 'come', 'ogd', 'something', 
'emoc'] sorry I am a new in coding

Comment: @hackrack just tested it in my browser console, it works fine

Comment: how I can call the function with argument can show me please really appreciate it

Comment: Ohh  Valentin Waeselynck please accept my apologies. It works, so sorry for giving hard time to you